# how to wrap different LINQ with different return and trace out the latency

Tags: c#, linq

I may have different public API methods for client to call, In different APIs I may use different Linq to query DB, which may return different type of anonymous list objects. now I simply write a wrapper which take Func> linq as parameter and output IList as return.

In the wrapper I will use stopwatch to log the latency, surely for every linq I will use ToList() as the last step to force linq to execute immediately.

However, in some API I may use the second linq which will join to first return of wrapper, then MSBuild errors a expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.

I am thinking out create a bunch of intermediate object to cast dynamic as real type object, however this will introduce some code rubbish I think so.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the code for your wrapper method? It will be a start to understand the problem better.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide sample code to illustrate the code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than wrapper, try a custom query provider that wraps the real one.  This would give you the ability to hook in and profile whatever you need, while not interfering with the expression tree